# Thymeleaf and Bootstrap Checkbox - How to use th:field with checkbox button group

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap checkbox button group ([link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/button-group/#checkbox-and-radio-button-groups)) with thymeleaf.
The Bootstrap checkbox button requires  `<label>` tag to be right below `<input>` in order to highlight the correct checkbox button.
The issue is whenever I add the `th:field="*{property_name}"` in the input field as below:

```
<input value="Text" type="checkbox" class = "btn-check" id="text" autocomplete="off"  name = "course_format" th:field="*{formats}">
<label class="btn btn-outline-info" for="text">Text</label>
```

**Thymeleaf  adds a hidden input element**

```
<input type="hidden" name="_formats" value="on">
```

just below my `<input type = "checkbox">` element
Therefore, the checkbox button **fails to get highlighted** although it gets selected.

**HTML code snippet**

```
<form method="POST" th:action="@{/submitCourse}" th:object="${coursePost}">
  <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="courseFormat" class="form-label">Course Format(Select all that apply)</label>
      <div class= "btn-group" role="group">
            <input value="Text" type="checkbox" class = "btn-check" id="text" autocomplete="off"  name = "course_format" th:field="*{formats}">
            <label class="btn btn-outline-info" for="text">Text</label>


            <input value="Video" type="checkbox" class = "btn-check" id="video" autocomplete="off"  name = "course_format" th:field="*{formats}">
            <label class="btn btn-outline-info" for="video">Video</label>

            <input value="Quiz" type="checkbox" class = "btn-check" id="quiz" autocomplete="off"  name = "course_format" th:field="*{formats}">
            <label class="btn btn-outline-info" for="quiz">Quiz</label>

            <input value="Certificated" type="checkbox" class = "btn-check" id="certificated" autocomplete="off" name = "course_format" th:field="*{formats}">
            <label class="btn btn-outline-info" for="certificated">Certificated</label>

      </div>
   </div>
 </form>
```

**Thymeleaf generated HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="/submitCourse">
 <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="courseFormat" class="form-label">Course Format(Select all that apply)</label>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <input value="Text" type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="text" autocomplete="off" name="formats">
          <input type="hidden" name="_formats" value="on"> <!-- generated by thymeleaf which is causing the issue(which is the checkbox button not getting highlighted -->
          <label class="btn btn-outline-info" for="text">Text</label>


          <input value="Video" type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="video" autocomplete="off" name="formats">
          <input type="hidden" name="_formats" value="on">
          <label class="btn btn-outline-info" for="video">Video</label>

            <input value="Quiz" type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="quiz" autocomplete="off" name="formats">
            <input type="hidden" name="_formats" value="on">
            <label class="btn btn-outline-info" for="quiz">Quiz</label>

            <input value="Certificated" type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="certificated" autocomplete="off" name="formats">
            <input type="hidden" name="_formats" value="on">
            <label class="btn btn-outline-info" for="certificated">Certificated</label>

      </div>
    </div>
   </form>
```